# Adding a column to an existing table in a Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Users model which needs an `:email` column (I forgot to add that column during the initial scaffold).

I opened the migration file and added `t.string :email`, did `rake db:migrate`, and got a `NoMethodError`. Then I added the line

```
add_column :users, :email, :string
```

again `rake db:migrate`, again `NoMethodError`.  Am I missing a step here?

Here's the migration file.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up  
    add_column :users, :email, :string  
    create_table :users do |t|  
      t.string :username  
      t.string :email  
      t.string :crypted_password  
      t.string :password_salt  
      t.string :persistence_token  

      t.timestamps  
    end  
  end  

  def self.down  
    drop_table :users  
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 702, accepted):

If you have already run your original migration (before editing it), then you need to generate a new migration (`rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string` will do the trick).
It will create a migration file containing line:
`add_column :users, email, string`
Then do a `rake db:migrate` and it'll run the new migration, creating the new column.

If you have not yet run the original migration you can just edit it, like you're trying to do. Your migration code is **almost** perfect: you just need to remove the `add_column` line completely (that code is trying to add a column to a table, before the table has been created, and your table creation code has already been updated to include a `t.string :email` anyway).

Comment: Just to be clear, we use the plural?  So it's `add_email_to_users` and NOT `add_email_to_user`?

Comment: Correct. Table names in Rails are always plural (to match DB conventions).

Comment: You can also use `rails db:migrate` for the final step.

Comment: Is it possible to create a new column on a particular position in a table. For example if i want to create new field "status" just after existing "email" field?

Comment: @neeraj you probably have the answer by now but for other seekers, yes you can as in e.g. `t.string :column_x, limit: 10, after: :column_y` (for Rails 4 at least)

Comment: FYI `after: :column_y` will not work with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 194):

Use this command on the terminal:

```
rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

and

```
rake db:migrate
```

to run this migration

Answer (score 90):

Sometimes `rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string` produces a migration like this

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
end
```

In that case you have to manually an [`add_column`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column) to `change`:

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

And then run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: 1) Should `rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string` this be run after `bundle exec rails c` or just within the terminal ?
2) Where is the generated file placed once we execute the query?

Comment: @sofs1 just in the terminal. The new file is created in `/db/migrate/`

Answer (score 29):

You can also do

```
rake db:rollback
```

if you have not added any data to the tables.Then edit the migration file by adding the email column to it and then call

```
rake db:migrate
```

This will work if you have rails 3.1 onwards installed in your system.

Much simpler way of doing it is change let the change in migration file be as it is.
use

```
$rake db:migrate:redo
```

This will roll back the last migration and migrate it again.

Answer (score 25):

To add a column I just had to follow these steps :

1. `rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string`

   **Alternative**

   `rails generate migration addFieldnameToTablename`

   Once the migration is generated, then edit the migration and define all the attributes you want that column added to have.

   **Note**: Table names in Rails are always plural (to match DB conventions). ***Example using one of the steps mentioned previously-***

   `rails generate migration addEmailToUsers`
2. `rake db:migrate`

Or

1. You can change the schema in from `db/schema.rb`, Add the columns you want in the SQL query.
2. Run this command: `rake db:schema:load`

   **Warning/Note**

   Bear in mind that, running `rake db:schema:load` automatically wipes all data in your tables.

Comment: I did this, but it did not redo the "scaffolding" and add the new column.  How can I do that "automagically"?

Comment: @John Wooten, you might wanna delete the Scaffold and go through it again. Drop corresponding migrations too.

Comment: to add a note: changing the schema without changing the migration may create issues with other developers maintaining the app.

Answer (score 9):

You can also add column to a specific position using before column or after column like:

```
rails generate migration add_dob_to_customer dob:date
```

The migration file will generate the following code except after: :email. you need to add after: :email or before: :email

```
class AddDobToCustomer < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :customers, :dob, :date, after: :email
  end
end
```

Comment: To save anyone wasting time, I (intuitively) tried before: :somecol and that doesn't work (it will still add the column, but will add it to the far right of the table)

Comment: Doesn't work in PostgreSQL. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3276

Answer (score 5):

You also can use special [change_table](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table) method in the migration for adding new columns:

```
change_table(:users) do |t|
  t.column :email, :string
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When I've done this, rather than fiddling the original migration, I create a new one with just the add column in the up section and a drop column in the down section.

You can change the original and rerun it if you migrate down between, but in this case I think that's made a migration that won't work properly.

As currently posted, you're adding the column and then creating the table.

If you change the order it might work.  Or, as you're modifying an existing migration, just add it to the create table instead of doing a separate add column.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this ..
  rails g migration add_column_to_users email:string

then rake db:migrate
  also add :email attribute in your user controller ;

for more detail check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also force to table columns in table using `force: true`, if you table is already exist.

**example**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20080906171750) do
  create_table "authors", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rollback the last migration  by

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

or rollback this **specific** migration by

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<YYYYMMDDHHMMSS>
```

and edit the file, then run `rake db:mirgate` again.