# What should I do when I need a new field in a table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field

I am a newbie in rails; my problem is:
I have a table for users, and I need to add more fields...

Where do I put that?
I tried to put it in the migration file, but the schema doesn't change when I run `rake db:migrate`.

This is in my migration file:

```
def self.up
 create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :username,         :null => false  # if you use another field as a username, for example email, you can safely remove this field.
  t.string :email,            :default => nil # if you use this field as a username, you might want to make it :null => false.
  t.string :crypted_password, :default => nil
  t.string :salt,             :default => nil
  t.string :nombres,          :default => nil
  t.string :apellidos,        :default => nil
  t.string :codigo,           :default => nil
  t.string :fecha,            :default => nil
  t.string :zona,             :default => nil
  t.string :institucion,      :default => nil
  t.string :frecuencia,       :default => nil
  t.string :pregunta,         :default => nil
  t.string :respuesta,        :default => nil



  t.timestamps
  end
```

And the schema is still without new fields

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "username",                     :null => false
t.string   "email"
t.string   "crypted_password"
t.string   "salt"
t.string   "nombres"
t.string   "apellidos"
t.string   "codigo"
t.string   "fecha"
t.string   "zona"
t.string   "institucion"
t.string   "frecuencia"
t.datetime "created_at",                   :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",                   :null => false
t.string   "remember_me_token"
t.datetime "remember_me_token_expires_at"
end
```

What should I do?

Comment: Create a *new* migration. Almost any Rails tutorial will discuss this. Or SO post; the first Google hit for me was [this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-a-table-in-rails).

Comment: thanks, that solve my problem.!! but i aave a doubt, if i make a new migration file for solve my problem, later i can delete that file without problems? because the fields are created... in that case, if i want to put my app in a hosting, i just need to have my principal migrate file with all fields that i need?

Comment: No, do *not* delete your migrations; they are how you roll back. There is no reason to delete them, either.

Comment: but if i move the app to a hosting, i can make again the migrate file with all the fields and not 2 files, 1 with some fields and other with a correction and more files... thats my situation :)

Comment: Why bother? And you wouldn't be able to roll back. Please just don't until you are more familiar with the framework.

Comment: ok, well thanks for the tip.! i wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something we're not mentioning here is adding the code into the migration file.

My steps to add a column go something like this:

```
# rails generate migration AddFieldName blah:string
```

Inside the migration file generated:

(btw, this typically looks like: db/migrations/20130330115915_add_field_name.rb)

```
class AddFieldName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :table_name, :blah, :string
    end
end
```

After making this change, I *then* run db:migrate. Then, the column is added to the database.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple migration

You can use a migration generator:
`$> rails g migration add_position_to_users position:integer` 
then run
`$> rake db:migrate`

## More complex migration

or more complex migration which rails also provide:
`$> rails g migration add_body_and_pid_to_users body:string:index pid:integer:uniq:index` 
`$> rake db:migrate`

More information about migrations can be found at railsguides
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: can you help me with a new doubt? i need a relationship between tables, how i do that?
is something like this
http://i45.tinypic.com/vfjtdj.png
i have user and loans table created, but how i create the relationship? i hope you can help me

Comment: for model https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/4729133 , i thinks you will able to create associations in your conroller =)