# Adding a column to an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I used following code to add a field `director` to an existing `movies` table:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :release_date

      # Add fields that let Rails automatically keep track
      # of when movies are added or modified:
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_column :movies, :director, :string
  end


  def down
    drop_table :movies
  end
end
```

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-a-rails-migration), but the difrence is I am insisting to use

```
 rake db:test:prepare command after i add my new field.
```

when i run `rake db:test:prepare` and then i run my `cucumber`, it gives me the erorr:

```
  unknown attribute 'director' for Movie. (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
```

this means that i failed to add the field `director` to the `table movies`,
So what is wrong here?

Comment: check in your controller that you have put this fuild "director" in params.??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a column to an existing table in a Rails migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-a-rails-migration)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
rails g migration AddDirector
```

then, in the corresponding migration
`def change
    add_column :movies, :director, :string
  end`

Execute , `rake db:migrate`

In the Movies controller, add "director" in the movie_params

Answer (score 0):

The `db:test:prepare` recreates the db using the `db/schema.rb`.

This will fix your issue:

```
bin/rake db:rollback
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do any migration, it gets saved in schema

Rollback that migration, make changes and then migrate it again

If for example 20150923000732_create_movies.rb migration is your last migration you can rollback with:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Otherwise you can simply down your specific migration with VERSION:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150923000732
```

After rollback your migration, change your migration file and migrate again.