# Rails 4 acts as votable retrieving record of the "voted" item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

I'm able to display the votes user likes, but I don't know how to display the actual record of the liked record. Whats the simplest way to retrieve user voted records?

**controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @liked = @user.votes
end
```

**show.html.haml**

```
= @liked.to_json
```

**Result:**

```
[{"id":5,"votable_id":8,"votable_type":"Post","voter_id":2,"voter_type":"User","vote_flag":true,"vote_scope":null,"vote_weight":1,"created_at":"2016-02-01T00:33:15.968Z","updated_at":"2016-02-01T00:33:15.968Z"}]
```

How do I turn this so I can just display the title, description, etc... from the Post record?

Answer (score 0):

Does the vote have post_id ? I assumed you have vote.rb and post.rb model.

vote.rb

```
belongs_to :post
```

post.rb

```
has_many :votes
```

In show

```
- @liked.each do |l| 
  = l.post.title 
  = l.post.description
```

Comment: No, I'm using acts_as_votable gem, so they don't have post_id

Comment: Well, you can just add an extra post_id column using migration. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4834906/3396429

Comment: But isn't the whole point of having the polymorphic association so you don't have to have the post_id column?

Comment: I assumed votable_id hold user id and post id.. Have you try using @user.votable

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found the answer by now—but here's what I do to show a list of things a user has voted on using the `acts_as_votable` gem. I am using Devise, so I am using `current_user` to specify the currently logged in User in the controller.

**controller.rb**

```
@liked_posts = current_user.get_up_voted(Post)
```

**view.html.erb**

```
<h3>Your 'liked' blog posts</h3>
<% @liked_posts.each do |post| %>
    <p><%= link_to post.title, post %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can have as many of those as you want—to display a collection of things a user has 'liked' across your application:

```
@liked_quotations = current_user.get_up_voted(Quote)
@liked_comments = current_user.get_up_voted(Comment)
@liked_stories = current_user.get_up_voted(Story)
```

Then, loop through those to show each collection.

There are two other methods that might be helpful—one to collect all voted-on things and another to collect all down-voted things:

```
current_user.get_voted(Post)
current_user.get_down_voted(Post)
```