# Adding attribute to already existing model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add `user:references` onto my already existing model. This is what I originally wrote:

```
rails g model Post title:string description:text
```

I do this to add the user:references by running `rails generate migration add_user_to_posts user:references`, I am receiving this error upon running `rake db:migrate`:

```
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists
```

I am reading the error and I understand I already have a User model, however, I want to add this attribute to the Post model, not the User model.

Db file:

Posts:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Trying to add the user to posts:

```
class AddUserToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Users:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :uid
      t.string :avatar_url

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :uid
  end
end
```

However, rake db:migrate gives me the error above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a column to an existing table in a Rails migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-a-rails-migration)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I have written exactly what that question has told someone to do above. But it is giving me the error that 'users' already exists, above. It looks like I am running the migration correctly but when I rake db:migrate it is giving me this error.

Comment: Try resetting your pending migrations first then try this again.

Comment: Same error. I have added to my post to help you.

Comment: Try to replace `add_reference :posts, :user, foreign_key: true` with `add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer`