# Adding a column to a model after the model is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating a model in Rails, I forgot to add a column "**strong text**" that I want. How can I add it to the model later?

Comment: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a migration on `console/terminal` as follows:

```
rails g migration AddColumnToModel column_name:column_type
```

then run migration `console/terminal` as:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

in your command line 
`rails g migration add_strong_text_to_model strong_text:string`
and 
`rake db:migrate`

duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-a-rails-migration)

Comment: `string` is superfluous there.

Comment: added incase if he is a beginner. :) after all he should get confused where to add the type of column